# is Impala a columnnar clustered database?

Tags: hdfs, impala, bigdata, database

I am new to Big data and related tools/technologies. I was going through the documentation of impala.

Is it true to say that Impala is a clustered columnar database?
and Impala needs heavy memory to compute/transform the data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Impala is not a Database.

Impala is a MPP (Massive Parallel Processing) SQL query Engine. It is an interface of SQL on top of HDFS structure. You can build a file structure over Parquet files, that are columnar files that allow you fast read of data.

According Impala [documentation](https://impala.incubator.apache.org/docs/build/html/topics/impala_intro.html):

> Impala provides fast, interactive SQL queries directly on your Apache Hadoop data stored in HDFS, HBase, or the Amazon Simple Storage Service (S3). In addition to using the same unified storage platform, Impala also uses the same metadata, SQL syntax (Hive SQL), ODBC driver, and user interface (Impala query UI in Hue) as Apache Hive. This provides a familiar and unified platform for real-time or batch-oriented queries.

Impala uses Hive Metastore to store the file structure and Schema of each file. Impala allows you to run SQLs queries in your files, and it will be responsible to parallelize the data in your cluster.

About the uses of Memory, you are partially right. Impala uses memory bound for execution, Hive uses disk based in classical map reduce over Tez execution. In newer version of Impala this allow you to use Disk Spill, that will help you with data that doesn't fit your memory.

Answer (score 1):

Impala integrates with the Apache Hive meta store database, to share databases and tables between both components. The high level of integration with Hive, and compatibility with the HiveQL syntax, lets you use either Impala or Hive to create tables, issue queries, load data, and so on.

Impala is not database.

Impala is not based on Map-Reduce algorithms. It implements a distributed architecture based on daemon processes that are responsible for all the aspects of query execution that run on the same machines.